# How to make this Ngon into a quad

Tags: modeling, topology

How can I make this Ngon into a quad? I if its possible I don't want to cut in-between the other faces because its making a very pointy  corner on the peak of the curve. I'm aware its a flat surface, but is it possible for theory sake to eliminate this Ngon?

[image]

[image]

Comment: it looks like you don't care about tris so you could make tris. But it's probably the whole topology that you should change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a Loopcut (Ctrl R) in front of the 5th vertex, then join with J.

[image]